# Node-Red debug node not showing unique payload for custom node

Tags: node-red

I was playing with a custom node plugin that sends multiple output, and it is not showing unique msg.payload in debug window as compared to running the same logic via a function node.

Snapshot of the simple flow using a regular function node (debug shows five unique payloads):
[image: Simple flow using a function node]

Snapshot of the same flow using a custom node wrapping the same code, but shows only the last payload repeated five times:
[image: Same flow with a simple custom node]

Simple custom node code:

```js
module.exports = function(RED) {
    function SimpleNode(config) {
        RED.nodes.createNode(this, config);
        var node = this;

        node.on('input', function(msg, send, done) {
            var name = msg.payload.name;
            var count = msg.payload.count;

            for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                msg.payload = "Hello, " + name + i;
                console.log("msg", msg);
                send(msg);
            }
        });
    }

    RED.nodes.registerType("simple", SimpleNode);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved it.  With Node-RED 1.0 a switch was made to clone messages coming from the Function node; this does not apply to custom nodes, which are executed asynchronously, and which therefore are resolving the multiple sends after the last message was set - hence all debugs got the same message.  Reference: https://nodered.org/blog/2019/09/13/cloning-messages